# FireFox 21.0 - This Connection is Untrusted on everything ever

Tags: firefox

I'm using FireFox 21.0 and am getting the This Connection is Untrusted message on every https site, including new Google searches. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: This is not something that you should just ignore. There is something wrong with your system, or a proxy intercepting your HTTPS traffic, or possibly a virus on the system.

Comment: As @TimB said, there is a possibility of something intercepting your browser. I also have heard that there are some "Internet Security" anti virus that does deep packet inspection and going through every single connection that you do by routing all your connection to localhost (as the anti virus is there) and then going outwards.

Comment: This sounds possible. I'm on a corporate network, and they did just recently release an announcement about implementing uh... something like the deep packet inspection firewalls. That's probably what's going on now that I think about it.

Comment: @ctote You might also have a look at my answer on [How to disable “This Connection is Untrusted” Certificate in FireFox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709095/how-to-disable-this-connection-is-untrusted-certificate-in-firefox/37080038#37080038) Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to disable HTTPS error pages:

```
Go to Tools > Options > Advanced "Tab"(?) > Encryption Tab
```

Click the "Validation" button, and uncheck the checkbox for checking validity. Not recommended, but it should stop them from displaying.

I'd advise making sure your system time is correct, if it isn't, that could be triggering all the certificate errors.

Edit: Yeah, as Tim said, unless you're doing some sort of dev testing, I would NOT disable HTTPS cert errors.

Answer (score 1):

I sit behind a corporate network and had the same problem and "fixed" it by going to [Options] > [Advanced] > [Certificates] > [Validation] and uncheck [Use the Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) to confirm the current validity of certificates]. HTH